# FireStore: permission-denied in get match

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

I have the next firestore rule:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{usuarios=**} {
        allow write: if get(/usuarios/$(request.auth.uid)).data.level == 0 || get(/usuarios/$(request.auth.uid)).level == 0;
    }
  }
}
```

And I get "permission-denied" when I tried this query:

```
firebase.firestore().collection('usuarios').doc(uid).set({...});
```

This is my DB actually:

[image]

pd: I want to add info about new users in my db (by his UID)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's going to be very expensive and inefficient since you pay per `get` request. Instead, you should write your rules as if you're defining the database's structure. Here's what I mean:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /usuarios/{uid} {
      // Give write access to any field within the document who's id is the uid
      // Add other validation as needed.
      allow write: if uid == request.auth.uid
          // Give admin access to anyone who's `level == 0`
          // Make sure to add the `databases...` boilerplate
          || get(/databases/$(database)/documents/usuarios/$(request.auth.uid)).data.level == 0;

      // If necessary, give access to sub-collections.
      // (We can't do it for uid or it will become a path object that we can't use as a string.)
      /{sub=**} {
        allow write: if uid == request.auth.uid;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you'd like to see fully flushed-out rules that are doing something very similar, I have an [open source exemple](https://github.com/SUPERCILEX/Robot-Scouter/blob/82baa16a17a30dc68e75778cdc4046c6b22a0a30/firebase/firestore.rules#L72-L108). Cheers!

Comment: Sorry but I need a user with “level” 0 can write in all other users, it is like an admin. With your rules the user only can write in his own “profile” yes?

Comment: Oh, got it. See my updated answer (I added an OR statement for the admin access).